# Using ng-repeat on a JSON object doesn't work - why?

Tags: json, angularjs, google-calendar-api

I can't seem to iterate over a JSON object using ng-repeat. I did test it directly by index and it works, but just can't seem to loop and print. What am I doing wrong? **[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/kpdrb8bf/)**.

**Here's my code:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>

    <ul ng-repeat="event in events">
        <li>{{ event.feed.entry.title.$t }}</li>    
    </ul>

    <!-- testing single entry here - it works! -->
    <small>{{ events.feed.entry[0].title.$t }}</small>

</div>

</div>
```

**The script:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var feedUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ogmda.com_89pas0l9jbhpf053atd83hdj30%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json';

app.controller('Ctrl', function($http, $scope) {
$http.get(feedUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.events = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Your JsFiddle isn't going to work because it's blocked by CORS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3ydLvot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you iterate over the whole data returned by the calendar query, and not over the entries themselves. Change your `ul` to:

```
<ul ng-repeat="entry in events.feed.entry">
    <li>{{ entry.title.$t }}</li>    
</ul>
```